# Javascript function to disable checkbox

Tags: javascript, salesforce

I have a VF page with 3 checkbox fields C1, C2, C3. If one checkbox field is selected, the other 2 should be disabled. For this I have written a javascript function. This is working fine.

But I also want to check the city field of account,ie, if the Account city has a particule value "AB", then checkbox field C2 should be disabled. Can somebody tell me how can I do this.

```
<script>
function confirmDisbaled(ifchecked,id1,id2,id3) {  
document.getElementById(id1).disabled = ifchecked;
document.getElementById(id2).disabled = ifchecked;
document.getElementById(id3).disabled = ifchecked;
}
</script>
```

page:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox label="C1" id="c1" value="{!c1}" selected="true" onchange="return confirmDisbaled(this.checked, '{!$Component.c2}','{!$Component.c3}');"/>
        <apex:inputCheckbox label="C2" id="c2" value="{!c2}" onchange="return confirmDisbaled(this.checked, '{!$Component.c1}','{!$Component.c3}');"/>
        <apex:inputCheckbox label="C3" id="c3" value="{!c3}" onchange="return confirmDisbaledcl(this.checked, '{!$Component.c2}','{!$Component.c1}');"/>
```

The Vf page has standardcontroller Account.

Comment: Why not make them radio buttons if they're going to act like radio buttons anyway?

Comment: @Pointy how do you uncheck radio button?

Comment: @PeterSzymkowski well one trick I've used is to have a "Clear" `<label>` element set up as being "for" a hidden radio button whose name matches the set of visible ones. That way there's an explicit way to clear the set (if a visible "None of the above" radio button is desired).

Comment: .. or you can write script :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(id2).disabled = ifchecked || document.getElementById('city').value == 'AB'
```